# Performance stats table

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

Is bigger percentage value in tables with computerisons good or not?

[image: pgadmin 3 - table info]

Comment: The bigger - the better. It's a hit-miss ratio.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) I wasn't sure, if it was CPU usage or RAM usage within one selft-test query... So the goal is to have 100%?

Comment: You cannot have 100% for obvious math reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bigger - the better. It's a hit-miss ratio.